# What happens when you top up a fully withdrawn validator?

Tags: proof-of-stake, validators, withdrawal

Does it automatically get withdrawn to original the withdrawal credentials of the validator? Please give references to the spec and/or eth2book.info when answering.

Answer (score 0):

https://ethereum.org/en/staking/withdrawals/#faq

> Once a validator has exited and its full balance has been withdrawn, any additional funds deposited to that validator will automatically be transferred to the withdrawal address during the next validator sweep. To re-stake ETH, a new validator must be activated.